# Copy multiple xls files data to single file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have Multiple files in a folder.i wants to copy all Files data (i.e.all columns to new sheet) to one new sheet.
E.g. file 1 Contains 5 columns of data and file 2 contains 10 columns of data and so on. this data should copy on new sheet like first 5 columns are from file 1 and then on the same sheet from column 6, the file2 data should be copy and so on.

i tried but facing some problems like i am able to copy first file data successfully but when i am going to second file , second file data is overwriting on first file. i want second file data to the next column.

Below is my code

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim search_result As Range   'range search result
    Dim blank_cell As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Path = "C:\Test\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
     sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    wbk.Sheets(sheetname).Activate

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Lastrow

 wbk.Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Copy

   Workbooks("aaa.xlsm").Activate
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  sheetname1 = ActiveSheet.Name
 Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wb.Sheets(sheetname1).Range("A1").Select
wb.Sheets(sheetname1).Paste
  Next i
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

plz help me......
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to advanced the Column value as well. At the line `wb.Sheets(sheetname1).Range("A1").Select` , you need to modify A1 to B1 and C1 etc. Use a simple loop that advances the column by 1 each time you open a new Workbook (Excel file).

Comment: Can't see why you're using the For i = 1 To Lastrow Loop

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying .....can you please make changes in my code and post it...Thanks for answer

Comment: Honestly, your code is written in such a way it can't be repaired, I've tried. it needs re-writing but even that will leave you with work today as it is not clear what some of the line were trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for answer ......i got the answer i just added one line next to "Next i" "  Cells(Selection.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Select"               ............. now the code is working successfully

Comment: Add I'm going to post an answer anyway as I can't walk away from code in this state! give me a moment.

Answer (score 1):

With the `For i = 1 To Lastrow` loop you are pasting the content several times and I was unable to correct it without significant change. As a result may I recommend using the below sample, I have added comments to describe what is happening.

```
Public Sub Sample()
Dim Fl          As Object
Dim Fldr        As Object
Dim FSO         As Object
Dim LngColumn   As Long
Dim WkBk_Dest   As Excel.Workbook
Dim WkBk_Src    As Excel.Workbook
Dim WkSht_Dest  As Excel.Worksheet
Dim WkSht_Src   As Excel.Worksheet

'Using FileSystemObject to get the folder of files
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\New folder\")

'Setting a reference to the destination worksheet (i.e. where the
'data we are collecting is going to)
Set WkBk_Dest = ThisWorkbook
Set WkSht_Dest = WkBk_Dest.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Look at each file in the folder
For Each Fl In Fldr.Files

    'Is it a xls, xlsx, xlsm, etc...
    If InStr(1, Right(Fl.Name, 5), ".xls") <> 0 Then

        'Get the next free column in our destination
        LngColumn = WkSht_Dest.Cells(1, WkSht_Dest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If LngColumn > 1 Then LngColumn = LngColumn + 1

        'Set a reference to the source (note in this case it is simply selected the first worksheet
        Set WkBk_Src = Application.Workbooks.Open(Fl.Path)
        Set WkSht_Src = WkBk_Src.Worksheets(1)

            'Copy the data from source to destination
            WkSht_Src.UsedRange.Copy WkSht_Dest.Cells(1, LngColumn)

        Set WkSht_Src = Nothing
        WkBk_Src.Close 0
        Set WkBk_Src = Nothing
    End If
Next

Set WkSht_Dest = Nothing

Set WkBk_Dest = Nothing
Set Fldr = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```